# XQUERY to update XML parameters

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xquery

Given the following XML snippet, for each distinct ElementID I need to check, that if the CurrentValue in one of the elements is different then update all the CurrentValues with the value which is changed.

```
<im:Element>
  <im:ElementID>1</im:ElementID>
  <im:CurrentValue>OldValue1</im:CurrentValue>
</im:Element>
<im:Element>
  <im:ElementID>1</im:ElementID>
  <im:CurrentValue>OldValue1</im:CurrentValue>
</im:Element>
<im:Element>
  <im:ElementID>1</im:ElementID>
  <im:CurrentValue>NewValue1</im:CurrentValue>
</im:Element>
<im:Element>
  <im:ElementID>2</im:ElementID>
  <im:CurrentValue>OldValue2</im:CurrentValue>
</im:Element>
<im:Element>
  <im:ElementID>2</im:ElementID>
  <im:CurrentValue>NewValue2</im:CurrentValue>
</im:Element>
<im:Element>
  <im:ElementID>2</im:ElementID>
  <im:CurrentValue>OldValue2</im:CurrentValue>
</im:Element>
-----
```

The result should be

```
<im:Element>
  <im:ElementID>1</im:ElementID>
  <im:CurrentValue>NewValue1</im:CurrentValue>
</im:Element>
<im:Element>
  <im:ElementID>1</im:ElementID>
  <im:CurrentValue>NewValue1</im:CurrentValue>
</im:Element>
<im:Element>
  <im:ElementID>1</im:ElementID>
  <im:CurrentValue>NewValue1</im:CurrentValue>
</im:Element>
<im:Element>
  <im:ElementID>2</im:ElementID>
  <im:CurrentValue>NewValue2</im:CurrentValue>
</im:Element>
<im:Element>
  <im:ElementID>2</im:ElementID>
  <im:CurrentValue>NewValue2</im:CurrentValue>
</im:Element>
<im:Element>
  <im:ElementID>2</im:ElementID>
  <im:CurrentValue>NewValue2</im:CurrentValue>
</im:Element>
-----
```

Comment: This seems more suited to XSLT. Can you use XSLT?

Comment: If you have several im:Element elements with the same element ID and different values, how do you know which one has changed and thus contains the new value?  Should the last value in the sequence be propagated to all occurrences of that element type?  Or is the key that the new values all begin with the string "NewValue" ... ?

Comment: The ways to find out the newValue for an element is to check the only value that is different from the values among all the occurrences of that particular elementID.

Comment: So if you have five occurrences of a given element ID, we are guaranteed either that all will have the same value or that four occurrences will have the same value and one will have a different value?  What if three have value A, one has value B, and one has value C?  And if we have two occurrences, one with the value X and one with the value Y, which is new?

Answer (score 0):

This seems more suited to XSLT. If you can use XSLT, here's one option...

**XML Input** (modified to be well-formed)

```
<im:Doc xmlns:im="im">
    <im:Element>
        <im:ElementID>1</im:ElementID>
        <im:CurrentValue>OldValue1</im:CurrentValue>
    </im:Element>
    <im:Element>
        <im:ElementID>1</im:ElementID>
        <im:CurrentValue>OldValue1</im:CurrentValue>
    </im:Element>
    <im:Element>
        <im:ElementID>1</im:ElementID>
        <im:CurrentValue>NewValue1</im:CurrentValue>
    </im:Element>
    <im:Element>
        <im:ElementID>2</im:ElementID>
        <im:CurrentValue>OldValue2</im:CurrentValue>
    </im:Element>
    <im:Element>
        <im:ElementID>2</im:ElementID>
        <im:CurrentValue>OldValue2</im:CurrentValue>
    </im:Element>
    <im:Element>
        <im:ElementID>2</im:ElementID>
        <im:CurrentValue>NewValue2</im:CurrentValue>
    </im:Element>   
</im:Doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:im="im">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="im:CurrentValue">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="(//im:Element[im:ElementID=current()/../im:ElementID]/im:CurrentValue)[last()]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<im:Doc xmlns:im="im">
   <im:Element>
      <im:ElementID>1</im:ElementID>
      <im:CurrentValue>NewValue1</im:CurrentValue>
   </im:Element>
   <im:Element>
      <im:ElementID>1</im:ElementID>
      <im:CurrentValue>NewValue1</im:CurrentValue>
   </im:Element>
   <im:Element>
      <im:ElementID>1</im:ElementID>
      <im:CurrentValue>NewValue1</im:CurrentValue>
   </im:Element>
   <im:Element>
      <im:ElementID>2</im:ElementID>
      <im:CurrentValue>NewValue2</im:CurrentValue>
   </im:Element>
   <im:Element>
      <im:ElementID>2</im:ElementID>
      <im:CurrentValue>NewValue2</im:CurrentValue>
   </im:Element>
   <im:Element>
      <im:ElementID>2</im:ElementID>
      <im:CurrentValue>NewValue2</im:CurrentValue>
   </im:Element>
</im:Doc>
```

Comment: The NewValue* doesn'y necessarily have to be of the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (1) that the new value to be used is the last one which appears on the elements of a given ID (so this answer is comparable to Daniel Haley's), (2) that the input and output are to be as conjectured by Daniel Haley, and (3) that your input document is at http://example.com/imdoc.xml, then something like the following XQuery module should do the trick.

```
declare namespace im = "im";

<im:Doc>{
  let $doc := doc('http://example.com/imdoc.xml')
  for $e in $doc/im:Doc/im:Element
  let $eid := $e/im:ElementID,
      $lastval := ($e/../im:Element[im:ElementID = $eid])
                  [last()]
                  /im:CurrentValue 
  return <im:Element>{ $eid, $lastval}</im:Element> 
}</im:Doc>
```

If assumption (2) doesn't apply, a slightly different formulation is:

```
let $input := doc('http://example.coms/imdoc.xml')
                  /im:Doc/im:Element
for $e in $input
let $eid := $e/im:ElementID,
    $lastval := ($input[im:ElementID = $eid])
                [last()]/im:CurrentValue
return <im:Element>{ $eid, $lastval}</im:Element>
```

Comment: The NewValue* doesn't necessarily have to be of the last element.

Comment: Then how are you deciding which element is the "newest"?

Comment: The ways to find out the newest value for an element is to check the only value that is different from the values among all the occurrences of that particular elementID.